# Le jeu de plateau et l'idée du « paragraph driven » ?

Tags: traduction, terminologie, jeux

Certains [*jeux de plateau*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8372891) (un [*jeu de table*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=frt&__index=frt&srchtxt=jeu%20de%20plateau&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0), un [*jeu de société*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeu_de_soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9)), utilisent des *paragraphes numérotés* dont le texte met en scène les conséquences d'un choix qu'avait fait le joueur auparavant dans la séquence de jeu.<sup>1</sup>

Contrairement au concept du [*livre-jeu*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livre-jeu), et plus particulièrement du « *livre dont vous êtes le héros* », où le choix est cantonné aux paragraphes qu'on enchaîne selon les indications, ici le paragraphe n'est qu'une composante d'un jeu plus élaboré; avec par exemple un plateau, des figurines, des cartes etc. L'emploi du paragraphe est assurément une particularité servant à sa classification mais n'en constitue pas son « interface ».<sup>2</sup>

[image: À gauche, du jeu de plateau; à droite, du livre-jeu].
<sup>*À gauche, un grille et des paragraphes d'un jeu de plateau; à droite, deux paragraphes d'un livre-jeu. J'aimerais distinguer la « caractéristique » du « format ».*</sup>

Comment exprimer de manière nuancée (et possiblement succincte) le recours aux *paragraphes* au niveau du scénario **et** leur *relation* avec ce jeu, dans la même phrase?

> Il s'agit d'un jeu de plateau + [?] + [« paragraph [driven](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/driven) »/une série
>   de paragraphes].

---

<sub>1. En anglais, on a l'expression « [*paragraph driven*](https://solowargamingshow.wordpress.com/2011/04/03/solo-mechanisms-a-comparative-review/) » comme mécanisme, dans le contexte d'aventure solo par exemple; autre [exemple](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/18613).</sub>

<sub>2. Voici un [**vidéo**](https://youtu.be/-rAj-M8UBHk?t=13m9s) traitant de la place du paragraphe dans la séquence d'un jeu (provenant d'une [liste](http://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/151812/top-10-paragraph-driven-games) de jeux ayant cette particularité). On explique que d'une carte, on en arrive à une situation, à laquelle on associe un choix, et où l'on croise des valeurs dans un index auquel on ajoute un élément aléatoire, pour enfin en arriver à un paragraphe particulier (à 17:00) où, dépendamment des caractéristiques du joueur, il se passe alors « quelque chose ».</sub>

Comment: Je n’utiliserais pas « jeu de plateau » comme synonyme de « jeu de société ». Pour moi, un jeu de plateau nécessite… un plateau. Un jeu de cartes, certains jeux de dés, la plupart des jeux de rôle (« sur table »), beaucoup de jeux « d’ambiance » (LIdJA vaincra !) sont des jeux de société sans être de plateau.

Comment: Sur l'image du milieu, je parlerais plutôt de *passages* que de paragraphes (et à mon sens plus on s'éloignera de *paragraph-driven*, plus la terminologie francisée aura de valeur). Dans la vidéo, le 22 semble être une liste (does it qualify as a paragraph ?). Le jeu me semble ***guidé par les fragments de scénario*** du livre, pour continuer de fournir des expressions synonymes. Évoquez les tous, et que le MJ reconnaisse les siens...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si je comprends bien, dans le type de jeu que tu décris :

- le livre de paragraphes est une **composante importante** du jeu, puisqu'il faut la mentionner
- mais **pas** au point que ça soit le format du jeu. Idéalement, la description met en évidence que le livre n'est le format du jeu, au contraire de ceux « dont vous êtes le héros ».
- la relation entre le livre et le jeu est que le livre **raconte** (*narre*, *met en mots*) et **guide** (*pilote*, *dirige*) l'action qui se déroule sur le plateau.

Je parlerais donc d'un jeu de plateau :

> piloté par les fragments de scénario du livre
>
> encadré par un système de passages narratifs
>
> dont l'action est dirigée par des paragraphes de récit

Comment: Nice! Whether intended or not, I especially like the double meaning that I see in "passages" as used here, with both meanings being totally relevant in this context.

Answer (score 3):

Je ne suis pas sûr que l'adjectif "narratif" marche tout seul pour votre premier [?] (comme il a l'air de marcher pour [Winter Tales](http://www.scifi-universe.com/actualites/14443/edge-nous-presente-winter-tales)), mais pour le 2ème [?], en cherchant un verbe qui va bien avec "data-driven", j'arrive à:

> **basé(e)s sur** [les [récits]](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/recit/);

qui donne en totale:

> Il s’agit d’un jeu de plateau **narratif** (ou **du genre
>   narratif**//[[*story-driven*](http://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=un%20jeu%20narratif)////[*storytelling*]](http://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=un%20jeu%20narratif)) où les actions des joueurs [, en fonction de leur situations et caractéristiques,] sont **basées** (ou axées) **sur**
>   **les récits** [en forme des paragraphes indépendants] **, numérotés indépendamment** [pour correspondre aux divers situations et caractéristiques des joueurs].

Et puis sans le verbiage entre crochets et parenthèses:

> Il s’agit d’un jeu de plateau **du genre
>   narratif** où les actions des joueurs sont **basées
>   sur les récits numérotés indépendamment**.

Answer (score 3):

Faisant appel aux éléments d'une autre [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13836/3177) :

> Il s'agit d'un jeu de plateau/société dont la [trame](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trame)
>   [narrative](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/narrative) est [alimentée](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aliment%C3%A9e) par un [système](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/syst%C3%A8me) de paragraphes.

La « *trame narrative* » est peu étayée mais j'ai un très haut niveau de confiance dans son idiomaticité et dans sa capacité de circonscrire les paragraphes à une composante et non au jeu entier; « [*contenant*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13845/3177) » peut aussi être utile à cette fin. Le verbe dans « *paragraph driven* » peut, à mon avis, passer de « *drive* » à « *fuel* », mais on peut penser aussi à *piloter*, *propulser* ou *mouvoir*. Enfin, en utilisant « *système* », on a moins besoin de tabler sur l'individualité des paragraphes.

Comment: Un jeu piloté par des paragraphes narratifs ?

Answer (score 2):

Selon les exemples donnés, le traitement des paragraphes correspond à un *[Jeu de l'Oie](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeu_de_l%27oie_%28jeu_de_soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9%29)* 'modernisé'.

Answer (score 1):

Selon l’importance du mécanisme dans le jeu, je dirais tout simplement qu’il contient ou est centré autour d’éléments de **[littérature interactive](http://www.litteraction.fr/presentation/livre-dont-on-est-le-heros/la-litterature-interactive)**.

Comment: Autant après m'être immergé dans la question je trouve cette réponse intéressante, autant je ne suis pas sûr que l'expression « littérature interactive » soit assez explicite pour le public de la description demandée. Si les gens connaissaient déjà le mécanisme, ils n'auraient pas besoin de description. Et *out of the blue*, *littérature* et *interactive* sont assez antinomiques, pour moi.

Comment: En outre, les livres dont vous êtes le héros me semblent être l'exemple par excellence de la littérature interactive, et le jeu décrit par l'OP cherche à s'en différencier.